# Consumir una api en laravel

Tags: laravel, api

Cómo consumir una webservice de call center me dieron una url para ser consumida por laravel tengo el formulario hecho y todo lo demás que me envia los parametros por jQuery

```
class CallController extends Controller
{
    public function showCall(Request $request)
    {


        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $res = $client->request('GET', 'http://mi_ip:8080/IntegrationWs/resources/callback/'. $request->input('telefono'));
        return response()->json([
            'status' => TRUE,
            'data' => $res->getBody()
        ]);
    }
}
```

Me devuelve error `cURL error 7: Failed to connect to 10.1.3.185 port 8080`

Comment: `mi_ip` es la **ip** local de tu computadora??

Comment: Has probado a acceder a esa ip usando el navegador? Prueba si puedes entrar en http://10.1.3.185:8080.

Comment: Si e accedido por url y funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo uso esta clase para facilitarme la vida, la he usado en PHP puro y en Laravel, puedes probar por Postman el servicio este bien y luego pasar al código

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Alex Diaz
 * WebServiceMangerCurl
 * 
 */
class WebServiceManagerCurl
{
    private $url;
    private $args;
    private $proxy;
    private $proxyIp;
    private $proxyUser;
    private $proxyPass;
    /**
     * WebServiceManagerCurl constructor.
     * @param string $url
     * @param Array $args Argumentos para enviar al Webservice
     * @param bool $proxy
     * @param int $proxyIp Ip con Puerto Ej: 190.0.0.1:8080
     * @param string $proxyUser
     * @param string $proxyPass
     */
    public function __construct($url, $args = '', $proxy = false, $proxyIp = 0, $proxyUser = '', $proxyPass = '')
    {
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->args = $args;
        $this->proxy = $proxy;
        if ($proxy) {
            $this->proxyIp = $proxyIp;
            $this->proxyUser = $proxyUser;
            $this->proxyPass = $proxyPass;
        }
    }
    public function get()
    {
        $curl = curl_init($this->url);
        if ($this->proxy) {
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, $this->proxyIp);     // PROXY details with port
            $proxyUserPwd = $this->proxyUser . ':' . $this->proxyPass;
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxyUserPwd);
        }
        /**
         * CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER
         * TRUE para devolver el resultado de la transferencia como string
         * del valor de curl_exec() en lugar de mostrarlo directamente.
         * - tomado de php.net
         **/
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('User-Agent: php-curl'));
        /**
         * CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER
         * FALSE para que cURL no verifique el peer del certificado.
         * Para usar diferentes certificados para la verificación se pueden especificar con la opción CURLOPT_CAINFO
         * o se puede especificar el directorio donde se encuentra el certificado con la opción CURLOPT_CAPATH.
         * - tomado de php.net
         *
         */
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        /**
         * curl_exec
         * Ejecuta la sesión cURL que se le pasa como parámetro.
         * - tomado de php.net
         */
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        /**
         *  curl_getinfo
         *  Obtener información relativa a una transferencia específica
         *  - tomado de php.net
         */
        $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
        if ($info['http_code'] == 200) {
            print_r($response);
            print_r($info);
        } else {
            echo "Curl error: " . curl_error($curl);
        }
        curl_close($curl);
    }
}
```

Para probarlo puedes empezar en un php puro para que lo entiendas, si no usas un proxy , cambiala a false y no envíes esos parámetros yo los pongo por que los debo usar . 
Entra a esta pagina y genera una URL que reciba tus solicitudes  https://requestb.in/ te va a dar algo como https://requestb.in/11tqqii1

Si te funciona aquí , tu script esta bien y ya debes revisar la url que consumes,

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: AlexDiaz
 * Date: 15/09/2017
 * Time: 8:17 AM
 */

include_once 'WebServices/WebServiceManagerCurl.php';

$webService = new WebServiceManagerCurl('https://requestb.in/11tqqii1', '', $proxy = true, $proxyIp = '177.777.777.7777:8781', $proxyUser = 'usuarioproxy', $proxyPass = 'claveproxy');
$webService->get();
```

Te va devolver algo como :

```
okArray ( [url] => https://requestb.in/11tqqii1 [content_type] => text/html; charset=utf-8 [http_code] => 200 [header_size] => 519 [request_size] => 196 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 20 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 1.922...
```

Ahora en laravel puedes crear un controlador con esta clase que te pase, agregar la ruta en el web.php (depende de la versión uso 5.4 )

Comment: Como seria su uso?

Comment: @vdjkelly pongo más información en la respuesta , si necesitas más información me comentas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta ahora solo me toca validar la numeración que sea minimo 7 digitos numericos
maximo 9
pero diferente de 8
osea no pueden ser 8 digitos esa validacion no se como hacerla en la validacion de laravel alguna idea de como

Comment: @vdjkelly Crea otra pregunta para que esta solo sea del tema que empezaste